# How to include validation fields to find user for a contribution page to avoid duplicate?

Tags: contribution-page, duplicate-contacts, prefilled

Although we have taken many different approaches, it was always been an issue with duplicated contact records.

What I thought is, if I could include few fields like

- First Name
- Last Name
- Email
- Post Code

and once that anonymous user fills in those fields mentioned above, CiviCRM would look for matching contact and prefills the details for a contribution page.

Is it something possible to achieve? Anyone have any suggestions, please? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your question suggests you may need to reread https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/stable/common-workflows/deduping-and-merging/ and then set up your matching rule as you describe and use that. if they match then it will add data to the existing contact rather than create a new one